# Ansible how to skip the loop if the list is empty

Tags: docker, loops, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I'm running Ansible and I try to make this task work. I have defined the default of the variable "docker_registries" to be an empty list: `docker_registries: []` I noticed that I will get error when running the ansible playbook if the list is empty. this is the error I get:

> fatal: [***.cloudapp.azure.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: None. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}

I'm trying to add the condition that if the "docker_registries" is empty the task continues without raising an error.
 this is the code for this task:

```
- name: Log into additional docker registries, when required
  command: docker login -u {{item.username}} -p {{item.password}} {{item.server}}
  become: true
  loop: "{{docker_registries}}"
```

I tried to change the loop to   `loop: "{{ lookup(docker_registries, {'skip_missing': True})}}"`
but I get the error

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full
>   traceback, use -vvv. The error was: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object
>   has no attribute 'lower' fatal:
>   [***.cloudapp.azure.com]: FAILED! =>
>   {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}

I'm pretty new with this. Can anyone help?

Comment: At least according to the error, you did not in fact pass an empty list to `loop:` you passed a `null` value (aka `None`); in either case, you may have some success with the [`default` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#default) as in `loop: "{{ docker_registries | default([]) }}"`

Comment: I did add the default before but no luck. I got this error after adding it:
fatal: [atefeh-atefeh-domain-lm0.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: . Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}

Comment: It would help if you shared the place where you are defining or passing the default value of empty list to docker_registries variable. If it is empty list, it would just skip the task altogether. If it is None, then you would get the error.

Comment: Quick question: Does the idea from @mdaniel work in this case, where the variable is defined but to the value `None`? Will the `default` filter apply or does default only work with completely undefined variables?

Comment: It does, but requires [the "boolean" argument](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#default) set to true: `hello {{ None | default("world", True) }}`

Answer (score 14):

You could use the [`when` statement](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) in combinaison with the [`iterable`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#iterable) Jinja test.
Because, well, if you want to loop over your variable, then it should be iterable.

```yaml
- name: Log into additional docker registries, when required
  command: docker login -u {{ item.username }} -p {{ item.password }} {{ item.server }}
  become: true
  loop: "{{ docker_registries }}"
  when: docker_registries is iterable
```

---

Based on the content of the variable, the when condition could still not do the trick, because the validity of the data passed to the `loop` will be considered first.

Now this said, you can use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in the loop declaration itself to come around this issue:

```yaml
- name: Log into additional docker registries, when required
  command: docker login -u {{ item.username }} -p {{ item.password }} {{ item.server }}
  become: true
  loop: "{{ docker_registries if docker_registries is iterable else [] }}"
```

---

Also mind that a string **is an iterable** in Python, as they are, simply put, a list of characters.

So you might want to go:

```yaml
- name: Log into additional docker registries, when required
  command: docker login -u {{ item.username }} -p {{ item.password }} {{ item.server }}
  become: true
  loop: "{{ docker_registries if docker_registries is iterable and docker_registries is not string else [] }}"
```

Comment: I still get the same error : fatal: [***.cloudapp.azure.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: None. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all guys. I had a line in my group_vars file which I had commented out the all docker_registries username and password and all, but I had not comment the `docker_registries:` line itself. That's why I was given the None instead of the empty list.

Comment: +1 because I stumbled upon this very problem when using AWX. I asked for the variable value in a survey and had the default set to a blank. This caused my variable do be defined but with the value 'None'. So yes, your very own answer helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ansible and Jinja have some surprising behavior:

1. The `loop` expression is evalutated *before* the `when` condition, so that won't help.
2. `{{ none | default('something') }}` evaluates to none.  `{{ none | default('something', true) }}` evaluates to "something".

i.e. you must pass true as the second parameter to default().

With this in mind, the solution is straightforward:

```
- name: Log into additional docker registries, when required
  command: docker login -u {{item.username}} -p {{item.password}} {{item.server}}
  become: true
  loop: "{{ docker_registries | default([], true) }}"
```

Also:

- `{{ '' is iterable }}` returns true, so you have to check for strings too if that is a possibility.
- None (Python) should be lower case none in Jinja2 evaluation.